# Memory Error: sklearn Knearest Neighbor knn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a Windows 10 64bit 12gb RAM core i5.

right now im testing with amazon dataset around 30k

246621 items in training data, 61656 in test data

i have try with other machine learning in scikit learn works fine but with Knn got problem with memory error.

my code

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5).fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
prediction['knn'] = knn.predict(X_test_tfidf)
accuracy_score(y_test, prediction['knn'])*100
```

my error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4d958e7f8f5b> in <module>()
      1 knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5).fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
----> 2 prediction['knn'] = knn.predict(X_test_tfidf)
      3 accuracy_score(y_test, prediction['knn'])*100

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\classification.py in predict(self, X)
    143         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    144 
--> 145         neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
    146 
    147         classes_ = self.classes_

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    355             if self.effective_metric_ == 'euclidean':
    356                 dist = pairwise_distances(X, self._fit_X, 'euclidean',
--> 357                                           n_jobs=n_jobs, squared=True)
    358             else:
    359                 dist = pairwise_distances(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1245         func = partial(distance.cdist, metric=metric, **kwds)
   1246 
-> 1247     return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1248 
   1249 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1088     if n_jobs == 1:
   1089         # Special case to avoid picklability checks in delayed
-> 1090         return func(X, Y, **kwds)
   1091 
   1092     # TODO: in some cases, backend='threading' may be appropriate

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in euclidean_distances(X, Y, Y_norm_squared, squared, X_norm_squared)
    244         YY = row_norms(Y, squared=True)[np.newaxis, :]
    245 
--> 246     distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
    247     distances *= -2
    248     distances += XX

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    133     """
    134     if issparse(a) or issparse(b):
--> 135         ret = a * b
    136         if dense_output and hasattr(ret, "toarray"):
    137             ret = ret.toarray()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    367             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    368                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 369             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    370 
    371         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    538                                     maxval=nnz)
    539         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 540         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    541         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
    542 

MemoryError:
```

Comment: Is your python 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

You can try increasing the `leaf_size` proposed on the [KNeighborsClassifier docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)

> leaf_size : int, optional (default = 30)
>
> ```
> Leaf size passed to BallTree or KDTree. This can affect the speed of the construction and query, as well as the memory required to store
> ```
>
> the tree. The optimal value depends on the nature of the problem.

first set the `algorithm = "kd_tree"`  then try for example `leaf_size = 300`

Comment: Is there a demo or example that shows how leaf size affects memory use and time elapsed? I hope there is one, but I can't find it.